# Extract words within a string and store as a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
col1
/bill/works/out
/daniel/lifts/weights
/filip/drives/abroad
```

I want to extract the first word between the first two backslashes and store it as a separate column, for example:

```
col1                        names
/bill/works/out             bill
/daniel/lifts/weights       daniel
/filip/drives/abroad        filip
```

I have tried:

```
df[df[col1].str.contains("bill")]
```

But this only selected the first row in col1 and not the word.

Comment: `df['col1'].str.split('/').str[1]` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to make use of the split function within Python like done so here on an example string.

```
>>> data = "/bill/works/out"
>>> split = data.split("/")
>>> split
['', 'bill', 'works', 'out']
>>> name = split[1]
>>> name
'bill'
```

This should allow for you to do what you require for the columns.

To apply to your dataframe you could do the following:

```
df["names"] = df["col1"].str.split("/").str[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `str.split`:

```
df["names"] = df["col1"].str.split("/").str[1]
```